# каким должно быть правильное построение серверной авторизации через google на C# Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth2

Есть web приложение которое использует авторизацию через AddJwtBearer.
Клиентская часть написана на Vue.

Работает приблизительно так:

1. При регистрации пользователь от пользователя требуется почта, имя и
   пароль. Данные пользователя записывается в базу.
2. При авторизации на
   основании id пользователя и  строки секрета генерится tокен который
   отправляется на клиент.
3. http запросы от клиента имеющие в
   заголовке "Bearer ...token" считаются авторизированными. Кроме того, я всегда могу получить идентификатор клиента который могу прочитать из  User.Identity.Name и следовательно формировать данные для пользователя.

Теперь необходимо добавить авторизацию через сторонние сервисы (для начала Google).
Я научился получать данные о пользователе через google api. В том числе получать токен.
Но что делать дальше пока не знаю.
Как правильней встроиться в существующий механизм?
Я должен слать на клиент какой то другой заголовок авторизации?
В общем кто знает может где есть описание или пример?

Comment: А в документации гугла что написано? Вообще очень грубо говоря токен аналогичен идентификатору пользовательской сессии. Грубо говоря, когда юзер вводит вам пароль, вы генерируете свой собственный токен сесии и кладете его в куку. А здесь не свой собственный, а гугловый.

Comment: В документации не очень подробно все описано. Есть пример аудентификации для Мvc  приложения. Но у меня одностраничное приложение на Vue

Comment: Нужно отправить токен на сервер и там проверить токен и  выдать ему свой токен, но я не смог найти как проверить токен на сервере для core. Для меня только это сейчас и вопрос.